# Which parameters should be used for early stopping?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm training a neural network for my project using Keras. Keras has provided a function for early stopping. May I know what parameters should be observed to avoid my neural network from overfitting by using early stopping?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

[image: early stopping]

Early stopping is basically stopping the training once your loss starts to increase (or in other words validation accuracy starts to decrease). According to [documents](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) it is used as follows;

```
keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                              min_delta=0,
                              patience=0,
                              verbose=0, mode='auto')
```

Values depends on your implementation (problem, batch size etc...) but generally to prevent overfitting I would use;

1. Monitor the validation loss (need to use cross
   validation or at least train/test sets) by setting the `monitor`
   argument to `'val_loss'`.
2. `min_delta` is a threshold to whether quantify a loss at some epoch as
   improvement or not. If the difference of loss is below `min_delta`, it is quantified
   as no improvement. Better to leave it as 0 since we're interested in
   when loss becomes worse.
3. `patience` argument represents the number of epochs before stopping once your loss starts to increase (stops improving).
   This depends on your implementation, if you use *very small batches*
   or a *large learning rate* your loss *zig-zag* (accuracy will be more noisy) so better set a
   large `patience` argument. If you use *large batches* and a *small
   learning rate* your loss will be smoother so you can use a
   smaller `patience` argument. Either way I'll leave it as 2 so I would
   give the model more chance.
4. `verbose` decides what to print, leave it at default (0).
5. `mode` argument depends on what direction your monitored quantity
   has (is it supposed to be decreasing or increasing), since we monitor the loss, we can use `min`. But let's leave keras
   handle that for us and set that to `auto`

So I would use something like this and experiment by plotting the error loss with and without early stopping.

```
keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                              min_delta=0,
                              patience=2,
                              verbose=0, mode='auto')
```

---

For possible ambiguity on how callbacks work, I'll try to explain more. Once you call `fit(... callbacks=[es])` on your model, Keras calls given callback objects predetermined functions. These functions can be called `on_train_begin`, `on_train_end`, `on_epoch_begin`, `on_epoch_end` and `on_batch_begin`, `on_batch_end`. Early stopping callback is called on every epoch end, compares the best monitored value with the current one and stops if conditions are met (how many epochs have past since the observation of the best monitored value and is it more than patience argument, the difference between last value is bigger than min_delta etc..).

As pointed by @BrentFaust in comments, model's training will continue until either Early Stopping conditions are met or `epochs` parameter (default=10) in `fit()` is satisfied. Setting an Early Stopping callback will not make the model to train beyond its `epochs` parameter. So calling `fit()` function with a larger `epochs` value would benefit more from Early Stopping callback.

Comment: thank you, I still cannot understand the definition of min delta, from the documentation , Min Delta is define as the minimum change of monitored value, may I know how did Keras defines Min change of monitored value, is it referring to different between current Val loss and previous Val loss?

Comment: @AizuddinAzman close, `min_delta` is a threshold to whether quantify the change in monitored value as an improvement or not. So yes, if we give `monitor = 'val_loss'` then it would refer to the difference between current validation loss and the previous validation loss. In practice, if you give `min_delta=0.1` a decrease in validation loss (current - previous) smaller than 0.1 would not quantify, thus would stop the training (if you have `patience = 0`).

Comment: Is it make sence to decrease learning rate when val_loss not improved for n_epochs? and how can it be done?

Comment: @mrgloom Yes it makes sense. It wouldn't help with overfitting, but as you said, if the training loss (can't guarantee `val_loss` but it helps that too if you are using a good model) stops improving, reason may be that your learning rate is too aggressive or your loss function is not precise enough to traverse down to an optima etc.. I.E loss starts to be noisy or increase. Learning rate decay helps with that. You can use `decay` parameter on your [optimizer](https://keras.io/optimizers/) or setup a [learning rate scheduler](https://keras.io/callbacks/#learningratescheduler) callback in keras.

Comment: Note that `callbacks=[EarlyStopping(patience=2)]` has no effect, unless epochs is given to `model.fit(..., epochs=max_epochs)`.

Comment: @umutto I should clarify.. `model.fit` will perform so many epochs, by default. Providing an EarlyStopping callback with a patience value will not cause it to continue training past it's default stopping point, unless `epochs` is given. That way, you force it to keep training, unless the EarlyStopping conditions are met.

Comment: @BrentFaust That is my understanding as well, I've written the answer on assumption that the model is being trained with at least 10 epochs (as default). After your comment, I've realized that there may be a case that the programmer is calling fit with `epoch=1` in a for loop (for various use cases) in which this callback would fail. If there is ambiguity in my answer, I will try to put it in a better way.

Comment: With the EarlyStopping callback, does the resulting model object from `model.fit` return the best model or the one on which the training stopped (final epoch trained)?

Comment: @AdmiralWen Since I've written the answer, the code has changed a bit. If you are using the latest version of Keras, you can use the [`restore_best_weights`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/callbacks.py#L480&L483) argument (not on the documentation yet), which loads the model with best weights after training. But, for your purposes I would use [`ModelCheckpoint`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) callback with `save_best_only` argument. You can check the documentation, it is straight forward to use but you need to manually load the best weights after training.

Comment: @umutto Hello thanks for the suggestion of the restore_best_weights, however I am unable to use it,    ` es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=1e-4, patience=patience_,verbose=1,restore_best_weights=True)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'restore_best_weights'`. Any ideas? keras 2.2.2, tf, 1.10 what is your version?

Comment: @Haramoz ah sorry my bad, I haven't realized it wasn't released yet. It seems that the commit was after the last Keras version (2.2.2). It would probably be included in the next release or you can install it from the source (which could be unstable). I would recommend using [`ModelCheckpoint` callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint) in the mean time.

Comment: Yes man. I am able to use this feature already by installing keras from the source github.

Comment: Is not `patience=2` is very low? The model can start bad and then improve after some epochs, and you will  miss it. Why not to use higher `patience`, and use  `save_only_bast_model`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of EarlyStopping from another project, AutoKeras (https://autokeras.com/), an automated machine learning (AutoML) library.  The library sets two EarlyStopping parameters: `patience=10` and `min_delta=1e-4`

https://github.com/keras-team/autokeras/blob/5e233956f32fddcf7a6f72a164048767a0021b9a/autokeras/engine/tuner.py#L170

the default quantity to monitor for both AutoKeras and Keras is the `val_loss`:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/cb306b4cc446675271e5b15b4a7197efd3b60c34/keras/callbacks.py#L1748
https://autokeras.com/image_classifier/