# Keras: Optimal epoch selection

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, callback

I'm trying to write some logic that selects the best epoch to run a neural network in Keras. My code saves the training loss and the test loss for a set number of epochs and then picks the best fitting epoch according to some logic. The code looks like this:

```
ini_epochs = 100

df_train_loss = DataFrame(data=history.history['loss'], columns=['Train_loss']); 
df_test_loss = DataFrame(data=history.history['val_loss'], columns=['Test_loss']);
df_loss = concat([df_train_loss,df_test_loss], axis=1)

Min_loss = max(df_loss['Test_loss'])
for i in range(ini_epochs):
    Test_loss = df_loss['Test_loss'][i];
    Train_loss = df_loss['Train_loss'][i]; 
    if Test_loss >  Train_loss and Test_loss < Min_loss:
        Min_loss = Test_loss;
```

The idea behind the logic is this; to get the best model, the epoch selected should select the model with the lowest loss value, but it must be above the training loss value to avoid overfitting.

In general, this epoch selection method works OK. However, if the test loss value is below the train loss from the start, then this method picks an epoch of zero (see below). 
[image]

Now I could add another `if` statement assessing whether the difference between the test and train losses are positive or negative, and then write logic for each case, but what happens if the difference starts positive and then ends up negative. I get confused and haven't been able to write effective code.

So, my questions are:

1) Can you show me how you what code you would write to  to account for the situation show in the graph (and for the case where the test and train loss curves cross). I'd say the strategy would be to take the value that with the minimum difference.

2) There is a good chance that I'm going about this the wrong way. I know Keras has a callbacks feature but I don't like the idea of using the `save_best_only` feature because it can save overfitted models. Any advice on a more efficient epoch selection method would be great.

Comment: I believe you are intuitively looking for the concept of 'early stopping'.  Another post regarding this concept with Keras is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906048/keras-early-stopping) where you probably would be looking at the `patience` parameter.

Comment: @cdeterman Very interesting link. This might just be what I'm looking for. Will check it out come back to you if I have any questions.

Answer (score 4):

Use EarlyStopping which is available in Keras. Early stopping is basically stopping the training once your loss starts to increase (or in other words validation accuracy starts to decrease). use ModelCheckpoint to save the model wherever you want.

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

STAMP = 'simple_lstm_glove_vectors_%.2f_%.2f'%(rate_drop_lstm,rate_drop_dense)
early_stopping =EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=5)
bst_model_path = STAMP + '.h5'
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(bst_model_path, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)

hist = model.fit(data_train, labels_train, \
        validation_data=(data_val, labels_val), \
        epochs=50, batch_size=256, shuffle=True, \
         callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint])

model.load_weights(bst_model_path)
```

refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43906048/keras-early-stopping) for more info

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple example illustrate how to use early stooping in Keras:

- First necessarily import:

  ```
  from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint
  ```
- Setup Early Stopping

  ```
  # Set callback functions to early stop training and save the best model so far
  callbacks = [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2),
           ModelCheckpoint(filepath='best_model.h5', monitor='val_loss', save_best_only=True)]
  ```
- Train neural network

  ```
  history = network.fit(train_features, # Features
                    train_target, # Target vector
                    epochs=20, # Number of epochs
                    callbacks=callbacks, # Early stopping
                    verbose=0, # Print description after each epoch
                    batch_size=100, # Number of observations per batch
                    validation_data=(test_features, test_target)) # Data for evaluation
  ```

See the full example [here](https://chrisalbon.com/deep_learning/keras/neural_network_early_stopping/).

Please also check :[Stop Keras Training when the network has fully converge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478622/stop-keras-training-when-the-network-has-fully-converge); the best answer of Daniel.